# AngularJs DOM manipulation in directive

Tags: angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which shows a list of Users with their names as links.
Inside the the template of this directive I have following loop:

```
<ng-repeat="user in myctrl.users />
     <a href="" >{{user.name}}</a>
```

Now I want to add an attribute directive to all the anchor tags with 
with name edit-confirm-popup as shown below.

```
<ng-repeat="user in myctrl.users />
     <a href="" edit-confirm-popup>{{user.name}}</a>
```

What I want to do is whenever user click on link of user's name I want to show a popup with popup's html inserted as sibling of the anchor element. I don't want to repeat the popup html when directive is compiled rather I want to insert it dynamically when user clicks on the link.
              I am able to achieve following things :
   1) attaching click event listener on directive element that is anchor element in directive's link function.
   Don't know
  i) how I should insert the template as I want to?
  ii) I want the current user to be available in event listener so that I can check some conditions before I show the popup.
     Here is my directive code :

```
function editConfirmPopup() {

  function linkFunction(scope, iElement, iAttrs){
      console.log(iElement);
      iElement.on('click',function onEditUser(e){
         console.log(e);
         console.log('in event handler');
      });
  }
  var directiveDefinitionObject = {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
       user: '=',
       populateUser : '&'
    },
    controller: 'UserEditConfirmController',
    controllerAs: 'userEdit',
    link : linkFunction,
    bindToController: true
  };

  return directiveDefinitionObject;
}

angular
    .module('mymodule')
    .directive('editConfirmPopup', editConfirmPopup);
```

Comment: Take a look at how `$modal` from angular-ui does the modal approach and follow their lead (if you want to create your own modal directive)... but otherwise, the question is too broad, in my opinion

Comment: First thing this is not a modal popup requirement. I dont think its too broad as I have given specific scenario. If there is any alternative way to achieve the thing I am fine.

Comment: What is this "popup" then? Where is the popup's template coming from?

Comment: may be popup term created confusion. Its a simple notification I want to show and the template of the notification itself should be inserted dynamically when I  click on the anchor  tag, This notification html should be inserted as sibling of anchor tag

Comment: "notification" is just as confusing... are you talking about some HTML to be dynamically displayed when you click on an anchor? You could then just use `ng-if`

Comment: Yes. I dont want to use ng-if as that will make me put static html for notification for every user which I don't want to do.  I would like to rather compile the html on the fly and insert it as particualr anchor's sibling. I dont want to use ng-if/ng-show as that will make me duplicate the template for every user in the list

Answer (score 0):

`ng-if` directive conditionally appends (or removes) - not just shows/hides - the elements on which it operates.

Using the fact that `ng-repeat` creates a child scope for each iteration, you can then just use a simple toggle variable to decide whether to show/hide the additional HTML (that you call "popup"):

```
<div ng-repeat="user in myctrl.users">
     <a ng-click="showPopup = !showPopup">{{user.name}}</a>
     <div ng-if="showPopup">
       The "popup" HTML
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: AS I said this solution will make me duplicate the same template for every user. Rather I would like to dynamically compile and insert the template on particular anchor click. And right now I am doing the same thing albeit in different way by changing the style of the root element of the html to be shown on click. but concept is same as using ng-if

Comment: @ShaileshVaishampayan, it's not the same. `ng-if` actually appends (or removes) the element - check the resulting DOM - unlike `ng-show` or whatever you are doing with `display: none`

Comment: right but if I have 20 users in the list I have to keep 20 unique statuses to disable all and enable only one which is active and currently clicked. So the work behind the scenes is similar or same even if its lighter on DOM